# I need my array to return and array back to another variable while also including its previous array members, no idea how to go about it

Tags: javascript

This is the test code that it's supposed to pass

```js
function makeArray() {
    const array = [];
    const t = 10;

    for (let i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        array.push("I am a strange loop.");
    }

    return [array, t];
}

describe('loops', () => {
    jsdom({
        src: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'loops.js'), 'utf-8'),
    });

    describe('forLoop(array)', () => {
        it('adds `"I am ${i} strange loop${i === 0 ? \'\' : \'s\'}."` to an array 25 times', () => {
            const [array, t] = makeArray();
            const strangeArray = forLoop(array);
            const testArray = strangeArray.slice(array.length);

            const first = "I am 1 strange loop.";
            const rest = "I am 24 strange loops.";

            expect(strangeArray[11]).to.equal(first);
            expect(strangeArray[34]).to.equal(rest);
            expect(strangeArray.length).to.equal(t + 25);
        });
    });
});
```

this is my code to return the function to `strangeArray` what I am thinking is that 35 is the total number of members in the array and as the test pass requires me to have 'expect(strangeArray[11]).to.equal(first)' 11th value to be equal to my function return as 
"I am 1 strange loop."

```js
function forLoop(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
        if (array[i] === "I am a strange loop.") {
            return;
        }
        else {
            array.push("I am ${i} strange loops.");
        }
    }
    return [array,i];
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I have no clue what you actually want to do.

Comment: Can you describe what `forLoop` should actually do, in terms of input and output? Are you trying to say you don't want to modify `array` but return a new array instead? You can copy an array using `var newArr = arr.slice(0);`

Comment: basically i want to the array in my function code and have all the members of the array assigned to 'strangearray ' in my test code when 'strangeArray' is declared as a variable because this calls the function 'forLoop(array)' , this also includes the new members that are included in the function.

Comment: You're going to need to make it a bit simpler for me to understand. After you call the function `const strangeArray = forLoop(array);`, what specifically should `array` and `strangeArray` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean exactly but I guess you just want the test to pass? The problem is that the first loop has 'loop' as singular and your indexes don't work either since they would start at 11. That's why your code doesn't work. You can just push to the original array.

```
function forLoop(array){
  for(let i = 0; i < 25; i++){
    array.push(`I am ${i} strange loop${i > 1 ? '' : 's'}.`)
  }
  return array
}
```

Comment: this worked, but had to remove +1 increment on i, which i don't understand

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Got a bit confused with all those indexes. However, the test doesn't really make sense either, since the first entry in the appended values should be `I am 0 strange loop.` and consequently strangeArray[11] would be `I am 1 strange loops.`